# Query throws "IndexOutOfRange"

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I find this weird, i have this code :

```
string getBatchesQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), time, 4) AS Batch FROM Calls ORDER BY Batch";
SqlCommand getBatchesQueryCom = new SqlCommand(getBatchesQuery, connection);

SqlDataReader getBatchesQueryReader = myCom.ExecuteReader();

List<string> allBatches = new List<string>();

while (getBatchesQueryReader.Read())
{

    allBatches.Add(getBatchesQueryReader["Batch"].ToString());

}
getBatchesQueryReader.Close();
```

Now how could that be that `Batch` doesn't exist? maybe because i name it like that?

What should i do?

Comment: can you set the break point at `allBatches.Add(getBatchesQueryReader["Batch"].ToString());` and see what value does it throws an exception, maybe it could be `NULL`.

Comment: Your reader has only one column. Why did you not use getBatchesQueryReader[0]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The column doesn't exist because you are running the wrong command. Change `myCom` to `getBatchesQueryCom`.

```
SqlDataReader getBatchesQueryReader = getBatchesQueryCom.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: There will be another exception. I suppose it is simple misspelling in simplification of code for us

Comment: I'm not next to the code to check but i assume this is the problem, and no it's not a simplification Kiril, i'm just a plain idiot.